# Freeze column header while scrolling

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I want freeze all column headers while scrolling down. Also, I want to freeze the first four columns with data when I scroll vertically.

For the second part, I used the `FIXED` data property for the first four columns. It's working perfectly.

How do I freeze all column headers when I scroll downwards?

I am using SSRS 2005.

Comment: Check this artcile http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb934257.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to make the column header row repeat on each page, please refer to the steps below:

1. Select the Tablix.
2. In the grouping pane, click on the small triangle and select "Advanced Mode" to show static members.
3. In the row group hierarchy, select the corresponding (static) item of the header row.
4. In the Properties grid:

   - set KeepWithGroup to After
   - set RepeatOnNewPage to True
   - set FixedData to True

For more explanation, please refer to the MSDN blog Repeat Header / Keep Header Visible in Tables in RS 2008 at:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/robertbruckner/archive/2008/10/13/repeat-header-and-visible-fixed-header-table.aspx